# Escaping many values for SQL query using C# npgsql

Tags: c#, npgsql

Given SQL query example such as the one bellow and C# npgsql lib/driver, what would be you recommendation how to construct final SQL query if you want values to be translated to strings (escaped SQL values) which could be used in assembling of final SQL without the fear of SQL injection.

sample query

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
 (12, 'aaa', '2020-04-06T12:00Z')
,(13, 'bbb', '2020-04-06T12:01Z')
,(14, 'ccc', '2020-04-06T12:02Z')
-- ... (typically few dozens, max few thousands rows to upsert)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT table1_pkey DO UPDATE SET col2 = EXCLUDED.col2, col3 = EXCLUDED.col3;
```

With queries **not** cotaining multiple rows (section between VALUES and ON CONFLICT) one would use NpgsqlCommandBuilder with named parameters. But in this case the number of named parameters can be quite high as well as original template would have to be dynamicaly created anyway. 
So I'm looking for something close to **pseudo-method** with this signature:

```
string PgsqlEscape<T>(T value);
```

```
PgsqlEscape("aaa") == "'aaa'"
PgsqlEscape(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow) == "'2020-04-06T12:01:45.784Z'"
PgsqlEscape(false) == "false"
```

Comment: Either do seperate insert statements, or use a loop to dynamically add additional parameters to concatenate and build up your SQL string (which is safe because no input will be from the user) and simultaneously add parameters to your command builder. Each parameter can be numbered so that it lines up with the corresponding placeholder in the SQL statement.

Comment: "what would be you recommendation how to construct final SQL query if you want values to be translated to strings (escaped SQL values) which could be used in assembling of final SQL without the fear of SQL injection." - I wouldn't; I'd use parameters - either a row at a time, or by doing batches of (at most some number of rows that doesn't exceed the maximum parameter count); trying to escape inputs is just asking for trouble with SQLi